# What is the default value of `MAXERROR` in a Redshift `COPY` command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When using the `COPY` command in Redshift there's an option to specify `MAXERROR` - a number of row parsing errors that can occur before the query will be aborted.

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html#tutorial-loading-maxerror) doesn't specify the default value for this property. What is the default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for `MAXERROR` is zero. It's undocumented, and zero is not necessarily the value you'd expect, but if you want any tolerance for errors during `COPY` you will need to set this to a non-zero value.